# Get à 401 Unauthorized when trying to lint my gitlab-ci.yml (version 13.8)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Since monday, I'm not able to use the lint CI API from gitlab, which is documented here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#validate-the-ci-yaml-configuration

I'm working on a self hosted gitlab, and we updated gitlab to the last version (13.8.4).

I've noticed that the documentation has changed between 13.8 and 13.9, they mentioned

> Access to this endpoint requires authentication.

So I tried to generate a personal access token with full access (I'm admin), but I still get a 401.

Here is my try :

```sh
$ curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: P3r50Na1t0k3N" "https://my-domain.artips.fr/api/v4/ci/lint" --data '{"content": "{ \"image\": \"ruby:2.6\", \"services\": [\"postgres\"], \"before_script\": [\"bundle install\", \"bundle exec rake db:create\"], \"variables\": {\"DB_NAME\": \"postgres\"}, \"types\": [\"test\", \"deploy\", \"notify\"], \"rspec\": { \"script\": \"rake spec\", \"tags\": [\"ruby\", \"postgres\"], \"only\": [\"branches\"]}}"}'

# Result : {"message":"401 Unauthorized"}

# Other try

$ curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: P3r50Na1t0k3N" "https:///my-domain.artips.fr/api/v4/ci/lint" --data '{"content": "{ \"image\": \"ruby:2.6\", \"services\": [\"postgres\"], \"before_script\": [\"bundle install\", \"bundle exec rake db:create\"], \"variables\": {\"DB_NAME\": \"postgres\"}, \"types\": [\"test\", \"deploy\", \"notify\"], \"rspec\": { \"script\": \"rake spec\", \"tags\": [\"ruby\", \"postgres\"], \"only\": [\"branches\"]}}"}'

# same result: {"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
```

Has anyone run into the same problem ?

Thanks in advance

Takeshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [ongoing issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/321290) regarding the CI Lint API endpoint. It seems that authentication for this endpoint doesn't work when "signing up" is disabled on on-premise Gitlab instance. I guess the issue will be fixed in future releases.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't found it. I'll wait for the fix

Answer (score 2):

The user token's scope must grant read/write permission to yout gitlab instance's API (as you may see in the picture). The user hasn't to be admin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with the whole scopes checked, but still get à 401

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'https://gitlab.example.com/'
api = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, '/api/v4/projects')
private_token = 'xxx'
params = dict(private_token=private_token)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')  # username and password, different from login account, generally provided from ops
response = requests.get(api, params, auth=auth)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```