# Gitlab YAML API linter gives no output

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

### Issue

I am trying to use the Gitlab yaml API linting tool on an enterprise instance of Gitlab. However, I am getting an empty response (not just an empty json object, like absolutely zero output).

### Steps to duplicate

I am using a stripped version of the sample `.yaml` file shown on the [gitlab CI/CD tutorial](https://gitlab.us.lmco.com/help/ci/quick_start/index.md) page. The file is shown here:

```yaml
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
```

I am using the 1 line curl command as shown on the [CI Linting API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#validate-a-projects-ci-configuration) page.

If I use the command as given (replacing only the filename), I get

```sh
$ jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<.gitlab-ci.yml)" '.content=$yaml' \
| curl "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/ci/lint?include_merged_yaml=true" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data @-
```

I get the output `{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}`, which is to be expected as the API call requires an API key. I generate an API key in my profile and try again:

```sh
$ export TOKEN='xxxxxxxxxx'
$ jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<.gitlab-ci.yml)" '.content=$yaml' \
| curl "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/ci/lint?include_merged_yaml=true" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json PRIVATE-TOKEN=${TOKEN}" \
--data @-
```

When I run this, the output shows nothing. This is confirmed by a pipe to `wc -c` which outputs 0.

My expected output should be:

```json
{
  "status": "valid",
  "errors": [],
  "warnings": []
}
```

### Questions:

1. Why is no response a result of me using my valid API key (This is with a newly generated key)?
2. How can I fix this, and receive the expected output shown above?

Comment: If you remove everything but the curl command (including the `--data @-` option) do you get the response saying `no content`?

`{"error": "content is missing"}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your token as the `api` scope, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241354/6309).

Without that scope, you would get a `401 Unauthorized`, which would not be parsed parsed by `jq` at all.